# Creating an empty tiledMap using cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am looking for a way to create a tiledMap which i at runtime can set to a size as well as content. I am making a game which will have levels in lots of different sizes as well as different textures and I was hoping to find a way to generate the whole map in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [TMXGenerator](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/tree/master/Extensions/TMXGenerator) from the cocos2d-iphone-extensions project.

Keep in mind that cocos2d TMX maps can not draw more than 16,384 tiles (128x128 tilemap, single layer). If you need larger (and faster) tilemaps you should use [KoboldTouch](http://www.koboldtouch.com) (/me own product) which also supports generating TMX maps on the fly, plus a couple other goodies.